# NodeJS socket hang up while using Raspberry Pi with SIM and cellular internet

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

Im reading a CSV File to a string. After this i upload the data to the server with a post request. If the content is getting larger i get the following error:

```
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:628:14)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:499:23)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:387:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

However this error only occurs if i'm using the celluar internet. If i'm using a network cable everything works fine. I tested with a CSV file with 1000 rows and had no problems.
The hang up will come if i get something like 20 rows.

I looked up the error and tried a bunch of different things. For example i installed the agentkeepalive npm package and set the timeouts and sockets up, but it doesn't help.

The backend is a PHP script, where i write data to a database. If i don't send data and set a sleep in the php Script for 20 seconds everything works fine.

But if i do send data, i get the socket hang up after exactly 10 seconds.

Note: This is running on a raspberry pi 4.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You mean the PHP is running on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: No, PHP is running on a backend server from ionos (Hoster) but i wrote the backend php myself. On the raspberry i'm only running NodeJS.

Comment: So that means this is not a Raspberry Pi problem because it is your backend that is disconnecting your socket. Since it is exactly 10 seconds I strongly suspect that this is Apache/Ngnix connection timeout. Your Raspberry Pi and node.js has no problems at all